# Find fails if filename contains brackets

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, filenames

I'm trying to use find inside a loop to create a variable that contains a file matching the filename + desired string

**Example:**

```
file1.en.srt
file1.mkv
file1.pt.srt
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    for file in "${1%/}/"*mkv; do
        # Get filename to match against subs and audios
        filename="$(basename "$file" .mkv)"

        # Find matching subtitle file
        engsubs="$(find . -name "$filename*en.srt*" | sed -e 's,^\./,,')"   

        # Find matching audio file
        engaudio="$(find . -iname "$filename*en.ac3" -o -iname "$filename*en.eac3" -o -iname "$filename*en.dts" | sed -e 's,^\./,,')" 
    done
fi
```

It works if files don't contain brackets, but the `find` commands don't find anything for files whose names contain brackets. Why this is happening? I want to create a variable like `$en` that would contain `file1.en.srt`

Comment: Please don't just tell us "it works" and "it doesn't work". How does it fail? What error message do you get? Which part of it fails? How do you call this script? What is `$1`?

Comment: No error message, it just won't find anything if the filenames contains brackets []... I call this script from command line... $1 would be the path

Comment: please try to create a minimal code example for us to reproduce without your whole script.

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Also related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)

Comment: You should show some of your example filenames and search strings.  I've never had any difficulty finding files with brackets in their names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `[` and `]` are glob characters. For example, consider this file:

```
ba[r].mkv
```

When running your script on that file, `$filename` will be: `ba[r]` and, therefore, your `find` command will be:

```
find . -name 'ba[r]*pt-BR.srt*'
```

Since `[r]` is a single-letter character class, it means `r`. So your command is looking for a filename starting with `ba`, then an `r`, then any character(s), and `pt-BR.srt` and any characters again. You need to escape the brackets:

```
find . -name 'ba\[r\]*pt-BR.srt*'
```

The simplest way is to use `printf` and `%q`. So change this line:

```
filename="$(basename "$file" .mkv)"
```

To this:

```
filename=$(printf '%q' "$(basename "$file" .mkv)")
```

Or, without the command substitution around `printf`:

```
printf -v filename '%q' "$(basename "$file" .mkv)"
```

Comment: Yeah I just noticed now that I didn't need that `*` at the end of `srt` or other file extensions lol. And it worked...thanks so much <3. Do you think this could mess with other filenames containing `space`, `()`, `ç` or other special characters?

Comment: @Freedo no, the spaces and `(` will also be escaped. Try running `printf '%q\n' "a ho[r]i(b)le file"`.

Comment: `printf %q` is wrong in the general case. First the output varies greatly between implementations but even if we limit to the `printf` builtin of bash, it still uses different kinds of quoting for different characters. For instance, it prints non-printable characters or non-characters using the `$'...'` form of quotes from ksh93. Here you just need to add a backslash in front of backslash, `*?[]`. Or use zsh and its `b` parameter expansion flag.