# Find files (ignoring extension) that may contain spaces, based on a supplied text file containing this list

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, regular-expression

With my limited knowledge of Linux tools, I hit a wall.
Because my list of files contains spaces (space character), the "find" command fails to find any hits, but does not produce any errors.
The reason for this script is to help with (re)transcoding of previously already transcoded files, such as music or movies.

```
searchdir="/volume2/"
filename='list-in.txt'

n=1

while read line; do

echo "# $n : $line"
FILES=${line%.*}

find ${searchDir} -iname "$FILES.*" -type f

n=$((n+1))

done < $filename
```

I'm not sure where to go from here as awk or sed examples I found rarely deal with processing variables.

The input file would contain filenames in the form of:

```
Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -05- Breakfast In America.m4a
Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -07- Take The Long Way Home.m4a
Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -09- Dreamer.m4a
```

Not quote delimited, and no paths.

The output of the script would be the path and filename that best matches the above list.
Note that the source files and results have different file extensions:

```
/volume2/music/Supertramp/1990. The Very Best Of Supertramp/Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -05- Breakfast In America.flac
/volume2/music/Supertramp/1990. The Very Best Of Supertramp/Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -07- Take The Long Way Home.flac
/volume2/music/Supertramp/1990. The Very Best Of Supertramp/Supertramp [The Very Best Of Supertramp] -09- Dreamer.flac
```

Comment: Please [explain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741593/edit) how "_the `find` command fails_". Error message? Unexpected output? No output?

Comment: The file that contains spaces - is that filenames contain spaces, or the file contains blank lines (with or without spaces on them)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The issue is likely not the spaces (which are properly handled by your quoting of the expansion `"$FILES.*"`) but the `[` and `]` characters

Comment: ... see for example [Find fails if filename contains brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508462/find-fails-if-filename-contains-brackets)

Comment: I'm not sure why you even need `find` here.  You already have a list of filenames, so (as long as none of the filenames contain a newline character), you can just use `"$line"`in your `while read` loop.   What, exactly, are you trying to do?   find out if a given filename has a matching file with the same basename but with a .flac extension? some other non-lossy compression format or .wav? or any other extension? (I can't see much point re-transcoding lossy compressed files, you've already lost detail that can't be regained by transcoding again).

Comment: anyway, we may be able to suggest a better approach if we knew what you were trying to do.

Comment: To answer you cas, it is the reverse. I want to find the sourcefile for the lossy format. So, say you made a set of files in MP3 format, or movies in MP4 format and want to find the file they were created with (FLAC or HQ MKV), this is what my script is hoping to accomplish.

Comment: OK.  Running `find` once for each filename in `list-in.txt` still seems like a bad idea (find is slow. especially if it has to run dozens or hundreds of times in a loop).  Instead, cache one run of find in an array and iterate over that.   The trouble is that any reasonable way of implementing this task requires more complicated data structures than bash is capable of (e.g. one obvious method is to use a hash where each key is the basename of the filenames in your list-in.txt file, and the values are an array containing the full pathname of files matching the basename - i.e. a hash of arrays).

Comment: bash doesn't support nested array like that, or any data structures more complicated than a simple array or associative array (hash).  You say you need to run this on your NAS - does that NAS have awk or, better yet, perl installed? if not, can they be easily installed? (by "easily", i mean available as an optional package, not requiring you to compile & install it yourself).  awk's support for multi-dimensional arrays is fairly basic (can do it, but clumsily), but data structures like this are perl's bread and butter and would be the optimal choice of language.

Comment: That does sound more sensible. Yes, the NAS does have perl and awk.

Answer (score 1):

With the zsh shell:

```
set -o extendedglob

searchdir=/volume2
filename=list-in.txt
names=( ${(f)"$(<$filename)"} )
files=( $searchdir/**/(#i)(${(~j[|])names:r}).*(ND.) )
print -rC1 -- $files
```

In addition to case insensitive matching enabled with `(#i)` here, you can also enable approximate matching. For instance `(#a2)` allowing matches with up to 2 errors (omissions, insertions, transposition, different character).

- `$(<file)` expands to the contents of the `file`. Here it's quoted to prevent IFS-spitting.
- `${(f)expansion}` splits the expansion on line `f`eeds.
- `${file:r}` expands to the `r`ootname of the file (extension removed). When applied to an array, that applies to all the elements.
- `${(j[|])array}` `j`oins the array elements with `|`. With `~`, that `|` is treated as a glob operator (alternation).
- `**/` matches any level of subdirectories (including 0).
- `(ND.)`: glob qualifiers:
- `N`ullglob: no error if there's no match
- `D`otglob: also look for hidden files
- `.` matches only *regular* files (like the `-type f` of `find`).

Comment: So, to clarify in my own mind, `${(~j[|])names:r}` treats `|` as an (extended) glob operator because of the `~` flag, but does not treat `[` and `]` specially in the expansion of `names` because unquoted variable expansions are not subject to split+glob by default?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes `${(~j[string])array}` applies globsubst to that join `string` only, while `$~var` applies globsubst to the whole expansion (and `$=var` does splitting so `$~=var` in zsh is like the `$var` of  sh, something you almost never want).

Comment: Thank you Stéphane. Unfortunately, I should have also stated that this will be running on a NAS (Synology) for which I only have access to BASH. At least, by default.